# Bounds of double integral given a circle and a line

Tags: integration, circles

Calculate the double integral of the area between the function $$x^2+y^2=25$$ and the line $$y=-x+5$$ in the first quadrant.

Now, I am unsure how to choose the bounds for y, I understand that the bounds of x are $0$ and $5$ (squareroot of 25). Now, I'd choose the lower bound of y as either $x$ or $-x+5$ and the upper bound of y as either $-x+5$ or $sqrt(-x^2+25)$ ... but due to my absence for those lectures I am unsure and would be grateful for a hint.

Comment: @Clearly the area can be found easily without calculus, but it looks like someone wants you to actually do a double integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture.  The lower bound for $y$ is $5-x$; the upper bound is $\sqrt{25-x^2}$.

Comment: Thanks! It's what I was afraid of as now I wouldn't really know how to integrate for x after doing the integration for y - the result of the integration for y being $sqrt(25-x^2) +x-5$ ... The squareroot is giving me some issues.

Comment: Perform a trig substitution: $x=5 \sin{\theta}$, etc.